# Counting non-zero non-NaNs in four arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, count, nan

I have four arrays, all of which contain zeros and `NaN`s, and I'm trying to get a total count of the number of elements which are all nonzero, and non`NaN` across all arrays. MWE:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
array = np.random.rand(10,5)

array[0][0] = np.nan
array[1][0] = np.nan
array[0][3] = np.nan
array[5][2] = 0
array[5][4] = np.nan
```

If I type

```
np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(~np.isnan(array[1]), ~np.isnan(array[2]), ~np.isnan(array[3])))
```

I get an output of `4` as expected. But adding one more condition like

```
np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(~np.isnan(array[1]), ~np.isnan(array[2]), ~np.isnan(array[3]), ~np.isnan(array[9])))
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-36-02311cb3ca54>", line 1, in <module>
    np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(~np.isnan(array[1]), ~np.isnan(array[2]), ~np.isnan(array[3]), ~np.isnan(array[9])))

ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

Why do I get the error by adding one more condition?

Comment: Why are you using a bit-wise NOT?

Answer (score 0):

[`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) only takes two arrays and returns the element wise ***and*** of the two arrays. And the maximum number of position arguments it takes is 3, thus why you getting the error and it's not doing what you want it to do; A better option is to rewrite your logic as follows, and you can easily add more rows in the row indices list in this way:

```
(~np.isnan(array[[1,2,3,9]])).all(axis=0).sum()
# 4
```

or:

```
np.count_nonzero((~np.isnan(array[[1,2,3,9]])).all(axis=0))
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that you are using `count_nonzero` incorrectly.

From the docs it only takes 2 parameters: `numpy.count_nonzero(a, axis=None)[source]`  [numpy count_zero docs][1]

And also you can't call

So why not something like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
array = np.random.rand(10,5)

array[0][0] = np.nan
array[1][0] = np.nan
array[0][3] = np.nan
array[5][2] = 0
array[5][4] = np.nan

print(np.count_nonzero((array)) - np.sum(np.isnan(array)))
```

So you count all the non_zeros which includes the nan's.  So subtract those.

So do that for each array and add them.

e.g.

```
mySum = np.count_nonzero((array[1])) - np.sum(np.isnan(array[1]))
mySum += np.count_nonzero((array[2])) - np.sum(np.isnan(array[2])) 
mySum += np.count_nonzero((array[3])) - np.sum(np.isnan(array[3])) 
mySum += np.count_nonzero((array[9])) - np.sum(np.isnan(array[9]))

print(mySum)
```

Comment: I did it this way because you said you wanted the count of the nonzeros and non-nans.  NOT the count of zeros and nans.

Comment: @Jim421616 Have you found the answer you wanted?